# Load entire list beforehand and search or send a search request to the database everytime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of about 100,000 debit cards and I want to find the relevant card when I'm updating the list of transactions that are related to the card. I want to know whether it's more efficient to load the entire list of cards first and find the card from that loaded list or to execute a database query every time using Entity Framework?

```
//Scenario 1:
var cards = db.Cards.ToList();
foreach (var transaction in newTransactions)
{
   var card = cards.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CardNumber == 
   transaction.TransactionMean);
}

//Scenario 2:
foreach (var transaction in newTransactions)
{
   var card = db.Cards.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CardNumber == 
   transaction.TransactionMean);
}
```

Comment: I'm certain this can be done in a smarter way, such as a query that will fetch all the data you need without the loop. Can you add more code, e.g. what do you do with the `card` or the transactions?

Comment: Databases are optimized to do fast searches by using statistics and indexes. Programming languages like C#, Java or other high level ones might be faster if they work on memory but you need to consider the time loading the data into memory, delay between your database server, the looping/search method, etc. So in the big majority of the cases it will be faster to delegate the searching task to the database and only fetch the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if your table is properly indexed it is always faster to use a database query as databases are made to do fast queries over large datasets.

A database also supports caching which you would otherwise have to implement yourself to speed up similar or the same query.

And lastly it's never a good idea to transfer tons of data if you only need a tiny subset of that data, imagine having a slow connection and having to wait 10 seconds each time for the whole dataset to be received, instead of waiting 2s for the query to be sent and receiving only the relevant dataset.